# How can I solve make error, "make[1]: I: Command not found"

Tags: emacs, compilation, makefile, cygwin, mingw

I tried to compile emacs-24.4 for native Windows with mingw64-x86_64 packages and GNU make in Cygwin x84_64.

after finishing the ./configure script, when doing make, I got this:

```
[ -r "src/config.in" ] || ( cd . && autoheader )
cd nt && make all                          \
  CC='x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -std=gnu99' CFLAGS='-g3 -O2 -gdwarf-2' CPPFLAGS='-mtune=generic  -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ -DUSE_CRT_DLL=1 -I /cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs-24.4/nt/inc' \
  LDFLAGS='' MAKE='make'
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs-24.4/nt'
I . -O coff -o emacs.res ./emacs.rc
make[1]: I: Command not found
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'emacs.res' failed
make[1]: [emacs.res] Error 127 (ignored)
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic    -I. -I.   -mtune=generic  -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ -DUSE_CRT_DLL=1 -I /cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs-24.4/nt/inc -g3 -O2 -gdwarf-2 ./runemacs.c emacs.res -mwindows \
         -o runemacs.exe
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: emacs.res: No such file or directory
Makefile:224: recipe for target 'runemacs.exe' failed
make[1]: *** [runemacs.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs-24.4/nt'
Makefile:363: recipe for target 'nt' failed
make: *** [nt] Error 2
```

---

BTW, I alter the file build-aux/msys-to-w32 with command

```
sed "/s/pwd/cygpath/g" build-aux/msys-to-w32
```

to walkaround the error when running ./configure

```
bash: pwd: -W: invalid option
```

---

here is the **nt/Makefile** -- anyone have any idea how to solve this error?

```
### nt/Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.

# Copyright (C) 2013-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

# This file is part of GNU Emacs.

# GNU Emacs is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# GNU Emacs is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GNU Emacs.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# Avoid trouble on systems where the `SHELL' variable might be
# inherited from the environment.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# ==================== Things `configure' will edit ====================

CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -std=gnu99
CFLAGS=-g3 -O2 -gdwarf-2
version=24.4
## Used in $archlibdir.
configuration=x86_64-w64-mingw32
EXEEXT=.exe
C_SWITCH_SYSTEM=-mtune=generic
C_SWITCH_MACHINE=
PROFILING_CFLAGS =
WARN_CFLAGS =
WERROR_CFLAGS =

# Program name transformation.
TRANSFORM = s,x,x,

# ==================== Where To Install Things ====================

# The default location for installation.  Everything is placed in
# subdirectories of this directory.  The default values for many of
# the variables below are expressed in terms of this one, so you may
# not need to change them.  This is set with the --prefix option to
# `../configure'.
prefix=/cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs

# Like `prefix', but used for architecture-specific files.  This is
# set with the --exec-prefix option to `../configure'.
exec_prefix=${prefix}

# Where to install Emacs and other binaries that people will want to
# run directly (like etags).  This is set with the --bindir option
# to `../configure'.
bindir=${exec_prefix}/bin

# The root of the directory tree for read-only architecture-independent
# data files.  ${datadir}, ${infodir} and ${mandir} are based on this.
datarootdir=${prefix}/share

# Where to install architecture-independent data files.  ${lispdir}
# and ${etcdir} are subdirectories of this.  This is set with the
# --datadir option to `../configure'.
datadir=${datarootdir}

# Where to install and expect executable files to be run by Emacs
# rather than directly by users, and other architecture-dependent
# data.  ${archlibdir} is usually below this.  This is set with the
# --libexecdir option to `../configure'.
libexecdir=${exec_prefix}/libexec

# Directory for local state files for all programs.
localstatedir=${prefix}/var

# Where to find the source code.  This is set by the configure
# script's `--srcdir' option.  However, the value of ${srcdir} in
# this makefile is not identical to what was specified with --srcdir,
# since the variable here has `/lib-src' added at the end.

# We use $(srcdir) explicitly in dependencies so as not to depend on VPATH.
srcdir=.


# The top-level source directory, also set by configure.
top_srcdir=..
# MinGW CPPFLAGS may use this.
abs_top_srcdir=/cygdrive/d/workspace/emacs-24.4

# ==================== Emacs-specific directories ====================

# These variables hold the values Emacs will actually use.  They are
# based on the values of the standard Make variables above.

# Where to put executables to be run by Emacs rather than the user.
# This path usually includes the Emacs version and configuration name,
# so that multiple configurations for multiple versions of Emacs may
# be installed at once.  This can be set with the --archlibdir option
# to `../configure'.
archlibdir=${libexecdir}/emacs/${version}/${configuration}

# ==================== Utility Programs for the Build =================

# ../configure figures out the correct values for these.
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
# By default, we uphold the dignity of our programs.
INSTALL_STRIP =
MKDIR_P = /usr/bin/mkdir -p

# ========================== Lists of Files ===========================

# Things that a user might actually run, which should be installed in bindir.
INSTALLABLES = runemacs${EXEEXT} addpm${EXEEXT}

# Things that Emacs runs internally, which should not be installed in bindir.
UTILITIES = cmdproxy${EXEEXT} ddeclient${EXEEXT}

# Things that Emacs runs during the build process.
DONT_INSTALL = addsection${EXEEXT}

# All files that are created by the linker, i.e., whose names end in ${EXEEXT}.
EXE_FILES = ${INSTALLABLES} ${UTILITIES} ${DONT_INSTALL}

# =========================== Configuration ===========================

# MS-Windows resource files and resource compiler
EMACSRES = emacs.res
EMACS_MANIFEST = emacs-x64.manifest
WINDRES =

## Extra libraries to use when linking addpm.
LIBS_ADDPM = -lole32 -luuid

## Compilation and linking flags
BASE_CFLAGS = $(C_SWITCH_SYSTEM) $(C_SWITCH_MACHINE) \
              $(WARN_CFLAGS) $(WERROR_CFLAGS) \
              -I. -I${srcdir}

ALL_CFLAGS = ${BASE_CFLAGS} ${PROFILING_CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}
LINK_CFLAGS = ${BASE_CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}
CPP_CFLAGS = ${BASE_CFLAGS} ${PROFILING_CFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}

all: ${EXE_FILES}

.PHONY: all

## Install the internal utilities.  Until they are installed, we can
## just run them directly from nt/.
$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}: all
        @echo
        @echo "Installing utilities run internally by Emacs."
        umask 022; ${MKDIR_P} "$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}"
        exp_archlibdir=`cd "$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}" && /bin/pwd`; \
        if [ "$$exp_archlibdir" != "`/bin/pwd`" ]; then \
          for file in ${UTILITIES}; do \
            $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(INSTALL_STRIP) $$file "$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}/$$file" ; \
          done ; \
        fi

.PHONY: install uninstall mostlyclean clean distclean maintainer-clean
.PHONY: extraclean check tags

install: $(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}
        @echo
        @echo "Installing utilities for users to run."
        umask 022; ${MKDIR_P} "$(DESTDIR)${bindir}"
        for file in ${INSTALLABLES} ; do \
          $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(INSTALL_STRIP) $${file} "$(DESTDIR)${bindir}"/`echo $${file} | sed -e 's/${EXEEXT}$$//' -e '$(TRANSFORM)'`${EXEEXT} ; \
        done
        ${MKDIR_P} "$(DESTDIR)${datadir}/emacs/$(version)"
        $(INSTALL_DATA) ${srcdir}/README.W32 "$(DESTDIR)${datadir}/emacs/$(version)"

uninstall:
        rm -f "$(DESTDIR)${datadir}/emacs/$(version)/README.W32"
        for file in ${INSTALLABLES}; do \
          rm -f "$(DESTDIR)${bindir}"/`echo $${file} | sed -e 's/${EXEEXT}$$//' -e '$(TRANSFORM)'`${EXEEXT} ; \
        done
        if [ -d "$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}" ]; then \
          (cd "$(DESTDIR)${archlibdir}" && rm -f ${UTILITIES}) \
        fi

mostlyclean:
        -rm -f core *.o *.res

clean: mostlyclean
        -rm -f ${EXE_FILES}

distclean: clean
        -rm -f TAGS
        -rm -f Makefile

maintainer-clean: distclean
        true

extraclean: maintainer-clean
        -rm -f *~ \#*

## Test the contents of the directory.
check:
        @echo "We don't have any tests for the nt/ directory yet."

tags: TAGS
TAGS: ${EXE_FILES:${EXEEXT}=.c}
        ../lib-src/etags *.[ch]

## Build the programs
addsection${EXEEXT}: ${srcdir}/addsection.c
        $(CC) ${ALL_CFLAGS} ${srcdir}/addsection.c -o addsection${EXEEXT}

addpm${EXEEXT}: ${srcdir}/addpm.c ../src/epaths.h
        $(CC) ${ALL_CFLAGS} ${srcdir}/addpm.c $(LIBS_ADDPM) -o addpm${EXEEXT}

ddeclient${EXEEXT}: ${srcdir}/ddeclient.c
        $(CC) ${ALL_CFLAGS} ${srcdir}/ddeclient.c -o ddeclient${EXEEXT}

cmdproxy${EXEEXT}: ${srcdir}/cmdproxy.c
        $(CC) ${ALL_CFLAGS} ${srcdir}/cmdproxy.c -o cmdproxy${EXEEXT}

runemacs${EXEEXT}: ${srcdir}/runemacs.c $(EMACSRES)
        $(CC) ${ALL_CFLAGS} ${srcdir}/runemacs.c $(EMACSRES) -mwindows \
         -o runemacs${EXEEXT}

emacs.res: ${srcdir}/emacs.rc ${srcdir}/icons/emacs.ico ${srcdir}/$(EMACS_MANIFEST)
        ${WINDRES} -I ${srcdir} -O coff -o emacs.res ${srcdir}/emacs.rc
```

Comment: You have an error in the Makefile in the `nt` directory. Post that file.

Comment: Something is attempting to set a `-I` flag only the `-` has gotten lost or swallowed by something.

Comment: Put it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by

```
WINDRES =
```

is an empty variable, then in the target

```
emacs.res: ${srcdir}/emacs.rc ${srcdir}/icons/emacs.ico ${srcdir}/$(EMACS_MANIFEST)
        ${WINDRES} -I ${srcdir} -O coff -o emacs.res ${srcdir}/emacs.rc
```

the first argument is omitted then the '-I' comes to the first and bash consider it as an valid command.

By properly set the WINDRES variable, this problem is solved.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. What should WINDRES be set to?

Comment: don‘ bother compiling emacs (and all gnu things) on windows, just use a pre-compiled one. You also want to try out the [Msys2](https://msys2.github.io/)   ;)